# Using JavaScript to open 2 websites

Tags: javascript, redirect, dom-events, javascript-framework

I want to make a script that no matter where you click on that website with the mouse to open a link in a new tab, every 1 of 10 probability pick.

This is what I have so far

```
<a href="newwindow.html" target="_blank">New Window</A>
<a href="http://www.example.org" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','newwin');">click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
alert(random);
window.open("http://www.google.com","windowName");
</script>
```

I was thinking about an invisible div, that when you click it to disappear.

Also, after when the user opened that link, I have to make that he wont open it for the second time, so i have to make a session. This step its optional.

Comment: So, to clarify; every 1 in 10 clicks on a link element on the page should result in that target url opening a new window / tab?

Comment: I can't think of another usecase for this than SPAM :p

Comment: what? is for my website, i have an iphone related website, and now i try to make a much bigger site with android, blackberry ...

Comment: Can you tell me the url of this site so I can add it to my personal blocked domain list? Acts like this is why pop up blockers had to be developed.

Comment: i don't know what is so illegal ... i'm not killing nobody, i'm serious about this, this is what i want to do

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.onclick = function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);    // 0-9 randomly
        if (rand === 0) {
            window.open("http://www.google.com","_tab");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, it actually works, but isn't this affected by popup blocks?

Comment: It shouldn't be affected because onclick event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043557/how-to-open-new-window-through-javascript-when-pop-up-is-blocked ==> this is what i'm talking about ... and another thing, i hope this it will not be spam related, because i worked a lot on my SEO on my websites

Answer (score 0):

How about just this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.onclick = function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);    // 0-9 randomly
        if (rand === 0) {
            alert("1 in 10 chance!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

​

Comment: thank you, but after 100 click it is still showing alert("1 in 10 chance!"); ... the idea is just 1 of 10 to open another website