# How to open a link in a new window if it is blocked by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use window.open to open a page in new window but this is blocked by the browser and ask the user to allow the popup. Is there any other way to open a new window and display behind the current browser?

Hope you can help me out and appreciate for your help.

Comment: No, it's there deliberately. If there were another way to do it, that would be considered a serious browser bug and it would be fixed.

Comment: If you can't open it, then the user has chosen not to be bothered. That means you give up and the answer is - no, there is no other way for you to force yourself onto the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open new window through javascript when pop up is blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043557/how-to-open-new-window-through-javascript-when-pop-up-is-blocked)

Comment: To get around most built-in popup blockers, you need to call `window.open` from *inside* a `.click()` event (or possibly other event, I'm not sure).  You cannot call it from inside an AJAX callback.  if the popup is still blocked, then there is nothing you can do except tell the user to allow it.

Comment: There was but now depending browser, this is an endless battle. Search for javascript 'popupunder' but anyway, needs some user interaction like binding mousedown event to document

Comment: The user must fire an event: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Lo1pzt/1/

Comment: Please also consider using a modal instead, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's in the settings of the browser which you don't have access to using JavaScript.  So the answer is no.

The best solution would be to inform the user that you're using a popup and for them to allow it..
OR don't use a popup.